# How do I change a set array into a random sized array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, random

How do I change a set array sized into a random sized array chosen by the user.

Here is how I have it setup  for set a sized array. I just do not know how to convert over to a random sized....

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1a {

 public static void scanInfo()
 {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");    
int rows = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter number of columns: "); 
int columns = input.nextInt();

int[][] nums = new int[rows][columns];            

 static int[][] sample = nums;

}
   static int[][] results = new int[4][5];
   static int goodData = 1;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      analyzeTable();
      printTable(results);
   } 

   static void analyzeTable() {
      int row=0;
      while (row < sample.length) {
         analyzeRow(row);
         row++;
      }
   }

   static void analyzeRow(int row) {
      int xCol = 0;
      int rCount = 0;
      while (xCol < sample[row].length) {
         rCount = analyzeCell(row,xCol);
         results[row][xCol] = rCount; // instead of print
         xCol++;
      }
   }

   static int analyzeCell(int row, int col) {
      int xCol = col;   // varies in the loop
      int runCount = 0;  // initialize counter
      int rowLen = sample[row].length;   // shorthand
      int hereData = sample[row][xCol];  // shorthand
      while (hereData == goodData && xCol < rowLen) {
         runCount++;
         xCol++;
         if (xCol < rowLen) { hereData = sample[row][xCol];} 
      }
      return runCount;
   }

  /*   Start Print Stuff */
  public static void printTable(int[][] aTable ) {
    for (int[] row : aTable) {
      printRow(row);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  public static void printRow(int[] aRow) {
    for (int cell  : aRow) {
      System.out.printf("%d ", cell);
    }
  }
}
  /*   End Print Stuff */
```

I am now only getting one error at line 18: illegal start of expression. I do not think I have the variables defined correctly.

Comment: Youd do it similar to your `results` array but use variables instead of literals e.g `int  arr[] = new arr[var];`

Comment: For what reason are you trying to convert the set array to a random size one.  Doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write your code in order to use `ArrayList`'s:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

//Here you create an 'array' that will contain 'arrays' of int values
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> sample = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

then add each row:

```
sample.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

and add an element to a row:

```
sample.get(0).add(5); // get(0) because is the first row, and 5 is int
```

Of course you will have to modify your code to use this kind of array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change array sizes in Java, although it gets complicated when working with multi-dimensional arrays. I would recommend familiarizing yourself with the [Java Array docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

What you can do is create a new array of the desired size and then copying data from the old array into the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");     // get number of rows
int rows = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");  // get number of columns
int columns = input.nextInt();;

int[][] nums = new int[rows][columns];            // new 2D array, randomly 
                                                  // sized by user input
```

Is this all you're looking for?  Based off your question, that's what it seems like

If you want a method populate it with random `1`'s and `0`'s, Just do this

```
static void populate(int[][] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column.length; i++) {
            nums[row][column] = (int)(Math.random() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now `num` is a 2D matrix with random `1`'s and `0`'s